# Issue with ExecuteReader() of SQLDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am facing an issue when using the `ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo)` method of `SqlDataReader` when quering the View in the database.

my View should retrieve 4 columns. But with the below code, it returns 6 columns. The extra 2 columns are the Key field columns of the tables used in the construction of the view.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo); 
DataTable dt = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

In case of Oracle, the view is same as that of SQL Server and using the below code, i am getting only 4 columns.

```
OracleDataReader odr = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
DataTable dt = odr.GetSchemaTable();
```

Please suggest some solution for this issue for SQL Server.

Comment: If you don't want 2 extra columns with key info why are you using that command behavior? Have you tried with command.ExecuteReader(); only?

Comment: We needed the field information like "IsHidden", "AllowDBNulls", "IsReadOnly" attributes on the field. And i am able to retrieve them using commandbehavior. And also the views are created by user, so there will be different kinds of views. In this scenario, we are not having any KeyField columns in the views.

Comment: Why does it matter if you get two more columns?

Comment: User needs only those columns which are in the query and not any extra ones.